# Does PyCharm have an option to automatically add all unambiguous imports?

Tags: python, pycharm

Intellij has an option to add unambiguous imports on the fly. I have not seen this behavior in PyCharm: does it exist as a Settings / Preference that I have overlooked?  The option that would *seem* to cover this is already selected:

[image]

However any imports that are needed always result in a popup / Import Assist for *every* new import.  I would like the feature included in the `Amazon Lambda Editor`.  When I pasted in the the `unzip` functionality code the editor automatically added all of the required imports

[image]

Now why would a simple `lambda` editor be able to do this while the premiere `PyCharm` does not?  I do wonder if I were missing some option/setting.

Comment: According to the [official Pycharm help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html), it seems that it's only semi-auto imports. You have to invoke the pop-up to "automatically" add the import. The auto import setting you found is just to determine the format of the import, once you chose it from the pop-up...

Comment: I've so wanted this feature for both Python and Java for so long.